# Problem with CORS with PUT request on S3 proxy by API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I set an AWS API gateway proxying an S3 bucket for upload/download. I have set up GET and PUT routes and have turned on the CORS on the API gateway using the default parameters provided by AWS.

I'm testing the API with a very basic html app with a `fetch()` call to the API. If I run a GET request the API return the expected content (i.e. the content listing of the bucket I hit). However, when I run a PUT request with a form data containing a file I get the following CORS error:

> index.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://XXX.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/a-test-bucket-XXX/test.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:8080'  has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I also set the CORS on bucket like the following and still get the same error:

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I confirmed that running the same PUT request using POSTMAN return success.

I'm pretty new to frontend development. I spent several hours researching the internet for a solution with no luck.

What am I missing?

Ok, Here's some more testing:

Running a curl OPTIONS request from my terminal return a 500 error... here what I did

```
curl -v https://XXX.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/liftoffbio-data/ \
   -X OPTIONS \
   -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT" \
   -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type" \
   -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080"
```

Here's the returned answer:

```
> OPTIONS /dev/liftoffbio-data/ HTTP/2
> Host: XXX.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
> Origin: http://localhost:8080
> 
< HTTP/2 500 
< date: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 18:53:07 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 36
< x-amzn-requestid: 1f4fbecb-562e-4a8a-96e5-8c08a3fb07e4
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
< x-amzn-errortype: InternalServerErrorException
< x-amz-apigw-id: xxx
< access-control-allow-methods: GET,OPTIONS,PUT
<
```

Anyone has a suggestion for possible solution?
Thanks

Comment: Postman doesn't typically do a preflight and enforce CORS headers like a browser would.  You can test the preflight request by making an OPTIONS request just like the one your browser made (use the web development tools of your browser to view the OPTIONS request).  "does not have HTTP ok status" the status code of the CORS response is where to start looking

Comment: Sending a OPTIONS request with fetch in the browser rerturn the same error... I don't get it... Running a GET on the same URL return a successful Promise... This is weird to me...

Comment: Ok, running a curl OPTIONS request from my terminal return a 500 error... here what I did
```
curl -v https://XXX.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/liftoffbio-data/ \
   -X OPTIONS \
   -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT" \
   -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type" \
   -H "Origin: http://localhost:8080"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer following this [recipe](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3)

In order for the CORS to work the following AWS CLI commands need to be run:

```
aws apigateway update-integration \
--rest-api-id API_ID \
--resource-id RESOURCE_id \
--http-method OPTIONS \
--patch-operations op='replace',path='/contentHandling',value='CONVERT_TO_TEXT' \
--region AWS_REGION
```

and

```
aws apigateway update-integration-response \
--rest-api-id API_ID \
--resource-id RESOURCE_id \
--http-method OPTIONS 
--status-code 200 \
--patch-operations op='replace',path='/contentHandling',value='CONVERT_TO_TEXT' \
--region AWS_REGION
```

Replacing API_ID, RESOURCE_id and AWS_REGION with the right values for the API Gateway. I'm not totally sure what the patch operation does exatly but it seems to fix my CORS problem.

There seems to be no corresponding console functions for the 2 CLI commands.

Comment: However, this fix is working for only one file type at a time...

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? Make sure to update your answer if you solved your problem!